# Testcafe client function failing "An error occurred in ClientFunction code: ReferenceError: _from2 is not defined"

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to use a client function to access the values in child elements on a page, not necessarily the ones in this example, but ones which are difficult to find with provided testcafe selectors.

In defining a page object model I want to be able to access Next, Back and Save buttons on multiple iFrame modals, they can have different locations on the DOM depending on modal view, and do not have ids (product is an old one).

They do however all follow a similar pattern, they would all be child elements of a span, and contain a Display text and title bearing their name, through chrome Dev Tools Console I can access them with something similar to the following

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).find(el => el.textContent === "Next")
```

However when I try to call this as a client function in testcafe I get an error, the following is an example based on my approach but against testcafe site, which gives the same error.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
fixture `Client Function`
.page `https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html`;

const query = ClientFunction(() =>  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).find(el => el.textContent === "Filter DOM Nodes"));

test('Test query', async t => {
      const queryResult = await query();
      await t
      .click(Selector(queryResult))
      .wait(1500);
});
```

The error this gives is rather cryptic to me:

```
  1) An error occurred in ClientFunction code:

      ReferenceError: _from2 is not defined

      Browser: Chrome 71.0.3578 / Mac OS X 10.13.6

          6 |    .page

   `https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html`;
          7 |
          8 |const query = ClientFunction(() =>
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).find(el => el.textContent
      === "Filter DOM Nodes"));
          9 |
         10 |test('Login and register user', async t => {
       > 11 |      const queryResult = await query();
         12 |      await t
         13 |      .click(Selector(queryResult))
         14 |      .wait(1500);
         15 |});
         16 |

         at query (/Users/david/Documents/testcafe/demo/query.js:11:33)
         at test (/Users/david/Documents/testcafe/demo/query.js:10:1)
         at markeredfn

   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/api/wrap-test-function.js:17:28)
         at <anonymous>
      (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/api/wrap-test-function.js:7:5)
         at fn
      (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/test-run/index.js:239:19)
         at TestRun._executeTestFn
      (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/test-run/index.js:235:38)
         at _executeTestFn
      (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/test-run/index.js:284:24)



 1/1 failed (5s)
```

Does anyone know if this is a legitimate bug or an implementation error? Thanks - any pointers greatly welcome too!

Comment: Did you ever figure out where the error was coming from? I am experiencing a similar issue but do not see a possible explanation as to what the ReferenceError is referring to.

Comment: The error is a limitation of the `ClientFunction` in testcafe. See https://testcafe.io/documentation/402832/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info#client-function-limitations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rewrite the ClientFunction like this:

```
const query = ClientFunction(() =>  {
    const results = [];
    const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    allLinks.forEach(link => results.push(link));
    const foundElement = results.find(el => el.textContent === "Filter DOM Nodes");
    return foundElement;
});
```

But then you will receive another error:

`ClientFunction cannot return DOM elements. Use Selector functions for this purpose.`

The code inside a ClientFunction executes in the browser.

The code that calls this ClientFunction and get its result executes in a NodeJS process outside the browser.

What you are trying to achieve is called object Marshalling. You are trying to transfer a DOM object which lies in the browser process into another separate process. This can only be achieved through serialisation but DOM objects are not serialisable.

The return statement inside a ClientFunction must return a POJO (Plain Old Javascript Object).

You could achieve the same thing by using the Selector object like this:

```
const nextButton = Selector('span')
  .find('a')
  .withAttribute('title', 'NEXT')
  .withText('NEXT');
await t.click(nextButton);
```

If you need special filtering other than attributes and textContent you could write the selector like this:

```
const nextButton = Selector('span')
    .find('a')
    .filter((link) => {
        if (/* some condition processed on link element */) {
            // this link element is the one to be clicked
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: That's great hdorgeval, thanks for the tips, I used the code from your refactoring of my client function and put it in a selector function.

My only question remaining is why the original syntax of my client function gave the error it did - I would have expected the query to run fine but the return of the object would have been a problem based on what you said above?

Comment: @Dobhaweim, I agree with you that the `_from2` error is unexpected and weird. It might be a bug, Maybe you could open an issue on TestCafe.